# Building exe and app applications from swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am looking for a tool that can help me converting my swf to exe and app. I know that there are several options available. My application will be frequently updated so update feature is essentions for me. Does anybody know a converter that might help me?

Any suggestions are welcome!

p.s. As another option, I can make app and exe out of a loader app that will load main application module every time it is updated.

**IMPORTANT** (added 22.08.2011)

Guys, thank you very much for your replies, but if you read carefully my question you will probably see that my main concern is about build in update feature inside projector eg. Mac app will be able to check for new version of my app automatically...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an AIR application with native installers and use [air.update](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/update/package-detail.html) and [air.update.events](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/update/events/package-detail.html) for to push updates.

Answer (score 3):

You can use flajector or f-in-box developer's library.

Comment: I recommend f-in-box. flajector used only for converting files.

Answer (score 2):

You may already be aware of this, but there is an *existing* publishing tool you can use inside of Flash Professional.

The publisher is in different menus on different versions of flash (CS4 to CS5) and on different operating systems (Windows vs Mac) so I'll just give you the "hot key"

While inside of flash, press `Shift`+`Alt`+`F12` and that will bring up some publish options. For an `exe` file you will want to select **Win Projector** or the option with **.exe**. **Mac Projector** or **.app** will do the same for mac. Hit publish once your preference is select and viola, that's it!

Answer (score 2):

you really want to use flajector. Cool programm.